# Print dialog box settings - pass initial values

Tags: java, printing, awt, printdialog, page-numbering

In Java,
when I call print dialog box the pages are set print from 1 to 9999. Am splitting the pages based on my `JTable` row number.

If my table row count is less than 40 then whole printing is in 1 page else the left rows are passed into next page. So my page splitting is based on row count.

Is it possible to pass value to print dialog?

I.E, If row count is 60 page number to be printed is 2.. am I able to set it when dialog box appear?

Comment: **Can any1 help me please.....**

Comment: **Any one have an idea??? its urgent for me**

Answer (score 0):

try to call printerJob.setPageable(Pageable doc) before call printDialog.
doc parameter is instance of class which implements Pageable interface. It contains methods to set number of pages, page format etc...